# neo4j cypher count relations between same type of nodes

Tags: count, neo4j, match, cypher

I am too new in graph databases and I have a problem in getting data from model like this.

[image]

I am trying to count common likes between User1 and all other users in same group as user1. Here is the result I am trying to get for **User1**:

```
User , Count, Drinks
User3,     2, [ Cola, Beer ]
User2,     1, [ Cola ]
User5,     1, [ Tea ]
User4,     0, [ ]
User6,     0, [ ]
```

It seems easy task to do but not for me.

I can get the users and counts with users having relations with but not with users without relations. Please can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I propose has the following logic :

- Find the user 1
- Find other users that are not user 1
- Find an [OPTIONAL MATCH](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html) for a path between user1, a drink and the current iteration of the other user

This is based on the following test graph :

http://console.neo4j.org/r/xc3cqt

The query :

```
MATCH (u:User { id:1 })
MATCH (o:User)
WHERE o <> u
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:LIKES]->(d)<-[:LIKES]-(o)
RETURN o.id, count(r) as c, collect(DISTINCT (d.name)) AS drink
```

Result for your provided graph :

```
o.id    c           drink
2       1           [Cola]
5       1           [Tea]
4       0           []
3       2           [Beer, Cola]
6       0           []
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Solution was quite simple after all. Thank you very much!